# How to convert values like '2+3' in a Python Pandas column to its aggregated value

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a column in a DataFrame named fatalities in which few of the values are like below:
`data[''fatalities']= [1, 4,  , 10, 1+8, 5, 2+9,  , 16, 4+5]`

I want the values of like `'1+8', '2+9', etc` to be converted to its aggregated value i.e, 
`data[''fatalities']= [1, 4,  , 10, 9, 5, 11,  , 16, 9]`

I not sure how to write a code to perform above aggregation for one of the column in pandas DataFrame in Python. But when I tried with the below code its throwing an error.

```
def addition(col):
  col= col.split('+')
  col= int(col[0]) + int(col[1])
  return col

data['fatalities']= [addition(row) for row in data['fatalities']]
```

Error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) what is different like pure python [eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice):

```
data['fatalities'] = pd.eval(data['fatalities'])
print (data)
  fatalities
0          1
1          4
2         10
3          9
4          5
5         11
6         16
7          9
```

But because this working only to `100` rows because bug:

> AttributeError: 'PandasExprVisitor' object has no attribute 'visit_Ellipsis'

Then solution is:

```
data['fatalities'] = data['fatalities'].apply(pd.eval)
```

Comment: didn;t know about the bug is there GH tracker for it?

Comment: @Datanovice - I once debug this bug so remember it.

Comment: you're right, I get `AttributeError: 'PandasExprVisitor' object has no attribute 'visit_Ellipsis'` for 101 rows

Comment: I even have nan values in the data column and when I am trying the above code its throwing me an error as below:
`
UndefinedVariableError: name 'nan' is not defined
`

Comment: @Naveenkumar - Can you try `data['fatalities'] = data['fatalities'].fillna(0).apply(pd.eval)` ?

Comment: @jezrael, this works for me now after filling the nan value with 0. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

using `.map` and `.astype(str)` to force conversion if you have mixed data types.

```
df['fatalities'].astype(str).map(eval)
print(df)
   fatalities
0           1
1           4
2          10
3           9
4           5
5          11
6          16
7           9
```